# bootstrap: selectpicker validation on blur with jquery validate plugin

Tags: javascript, jquery, twitter-bootstrap, validation

I am using bootstrap selectpicker for select. I am using jquery validate for validation purpose. On blur of selectpicker if user has not selected anything then dont trigger blur but if user has selected default option having value of "" then fire validation.

How to achieve this behavior?

Answer (score 0):

Basically jquery validation works on change value or change something on element value or behavior so on only click it will not fire validation error. YOu need to **trigger change event of selector click event**

I can **suggest to try code like :**

```
 $('.selectpicker').click(function(){
   if($(this).val() ==''){ $(this).trigger('change');}
 });
```